# How to capture stdout/stderr in junit 5 gradle test report?

Tags: gradle, junit, junit5

My gradle project uses junit 5 and I'm trying to get the test reports to show up on my build server. The XML report basically looks fine – it contains all the test classes and methods, but it is missing stdout/stderr printed in test methods. There is only some CDATA containing test metadata.

```java
@Test
void testToString() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    ...
}
```

XML report:

```xml
<testcase name="testToString()" classname="com.my.company.PairsTest" time="0.008">
<system-out><![CDATA[
unique-id: [engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:com.my.company.PairsTest]/[method:testToString()]
display-name: testToString()
]]></system-out>
</testcase>
```

Is there a setting to tell the gradle plugin to capture stdout/stderr? I looked around http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build but couldn't find any.

I am using `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M3` and `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-{api,engine}:5.0.0-M3`.

Comment: Output to stdout/stderr is currently not captured. Can you switch to using TestReporter instead? https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/documentation/src/test/java/example/TestReporterDemo.java

Comment: Most of the stdout/stderr are generated by the code being tested so they won't be able to use TestReporter.

Comment: (hit return too soon) @MarcPhilipp will there be plans to support capturing stdout/stderr in junit, or should I file a feature suggestion or PR somewhere? IMO the output is quite useful for understanding test failures on CI servers, esp. if the failures are not reproducible locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Marc Philipp mentioned, there is currently no support for capturing output to STDERR or STDOUT in JUnit 5, neither in the Platform nor in Jupiter.

If you would like such a feature, please raise an issue here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues

**Update** (2017.11.01)

FYI: as a proof of concept, I ported the JUnit 4 based `OutputCapture` rule from Spring Boot to JUnit Jupiter here: https://github.com/sbrannen/junit5-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/extensions/CaptureSystemOutput.java

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue.

Comment: FYI: I updated the answer to point to my port of the Spring Boot `OutputCapture` rule.

Comment: CaptureSystemOutput.java is doing job