# How to use JUnit 5 with Gradle?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit5

I am trying to use JUnit 5 with Gradle after I succeeded in running a JUnit 4 test.

**Expected result:** The JUnit 4 test gave a nice 'passed' in the output and an html report in `build/reports/tests`.

**Actual result:** The JUnit 5 test as below does not output anything besides `(...) build successful`, while I know the test is not actually run since there is no test log output passed/skipped/failed, and putting a `fail` in the test keeps the build successful.

Running `gradle test --info` yields `Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.` among a lot of I think mostly irrelevant output.
Surprisingly, it also says `Executing task ':test'` and `Generating HTML test report... Finished generating test html results` and similar for the xml in `build/test-results/test`, while the xml is not generated, the html shows no tests run and no errors, and the test is indeed not run.

What I also think very interesting, is that `gradle test --debug` yields

```
[TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Run :test STARTED
[org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitDetector] test-class-
scan : failed to scan parent class java/lang/Object, could not find the class file
[TestEventLogger]
[TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Run :test PASSED
```

while my only test contains

```
fail("test fails");
```

which I think is very strange!

My build file is

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
    dependsOn 'cleanTest' // run tests every time

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs 'test'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // when using this, it worked with a junit 4 test
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    // this should be needed for junit 5 (using M4 is required since IJ 2017.1.2
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M4")
}

test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

My test is

```
package mypackage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class HelloWorldTest {
    @Test
    public void testHelloWorld(){
        assertEquals(2, 1+1, "message");
    }
}
```

My folder structure is, using package `mypackage`,

```
java-template-project
--- src
    --- mypackage
        --- HelloWorld.java
--- test
    --- mypackage
        --- HelloWorldTest.java
```

and in IntelliJ 2017.1.3, which I am using, the module structure looks like this

```
java-template-project
--- java-template-project_main
    --- src/mypackage
        --- HelloWorld(.java)
--- java-template-project_test
    --- test/mypackage
        --- HelloWorldTest(.java)
```

because Gradle nowadays wants the source and tests in their own package.

**What I tried**

Obviously this is not the first question about this topic, all the relevant questions I found are

- [Gradle project running jUnit 5 tests in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293901/gradle-project-running-junit-5-tests-in-intellij)

  But as you can see this is for older versions of IntelliJ, and I am already using the syntax for IJ 2016.3.3 and higher according to one of the answers, in  in the one JUnit dependency line, so that should be okay.
- [Upgrade from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 in intellij with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576011/upgrade-from-junit-4-to-junit-5-in-intellij-with-gradle)

  Links back to above question, and links to this [Jetbrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/) which uses the same line as above question. Also links to:
- [Integrate JUnit 5 tests results with Intellij test report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576108/integrate-junit-5-tests-results-with-intellij-test-report)
  This one shows, in the question, as dependency also

  ```
   testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.0.0-M1")
  ```

  which is explained in [Why were JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage separated When I Running TestCase in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822189/why-were-junit-jupiter-and-junit-vintage-separated-when-i-running-testcase-in-in)
  Well, when I ran it, the output showed it couldn't find this version but according to the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine/4.12.0-M4) this one is for JUnit 5:

  ```
   testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0-M4")
  ```

  The answers there note that you can just run the tests within IntelliJ since the later versions have JUnit 5 support. I know, and the test runs fine when I run from within IntelliJ. But I want to use Gradle (and Travis, which needs dependency management).
- [How to capture stdout/stderr in junit 5 gradle test report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151448/how-to-capture-stdout-stderr-in-junit-5-gradle-test-report)

  I tried using

  ```
   testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M3")
   testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M3")
  ```

  but results didn't change.

  My template project is located on https://github.com/PHPirates/java-template-project but this question should contain all information necessary.

Comment: Had the same issue. Found out that @Test should be imported from 'org.junit.jupiter.api' (Junit5 @Test) instead of `org.junit` (Junit4 @Test)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need the engines for both JUnit versions, and you need to apply the JUnit platform gradle plugin. I do not see that in your gradle file. Here is a working gradle build executing both JUnit 4 and 5:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M4")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
...

dependencies {
...
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
    testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0-M4")

    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M4")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M4")

    // Enable use of the JUnitPlatform Runner within the IDE
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.0-M4")
}

junitPlatform {
    details 'tree'
}
```

See the [JUnit doc](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle) form more information on that.

Answer (score 60):

## New: JUnit 5 support in Gradle 4.6

As pointed out [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/828#issuecomment-368549611) from Gradle 4.6 onwards JUnit 5 is supported!
Official release notes of 4.6 (at the moment of editing the latest, but check the [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases) to make sure you use the latest version) [at docs.gradle.org](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#junit-5-support). The old setup will still work, but using this makes the build file a lot cleaner.

[Edit May 2019] As @deFreitas pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55109990/4126843), the JUnit documentation has improved and now they provide a complete example at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.4.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle, see especially the [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.4.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle) there. Fortunately it turns out to be effectively the same as the one from this answer.

**Update Gradle**

First, make sure you are using the latest Gradle version, check latest releases [at their GitHub releases](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases). If that is for example 4.6, run in a terminal in your project location `gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.6` or make sure to update this line in your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`.

**How to use the built-in JUnit 5**

Then with the java files, directory structure etc. from the question the `build.gradle` file will be (using the new `plugins` block)

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3'
}

// These lines can be removed when you use the default directories src/main/kotlin and src/test/kotlin
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'test'
    test.resources.srcDirs += 'test'
}

// Java target version
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

test {
    // Enable JUnit 5 (Gradle 4.6+).
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // Always run tests, even when nothing changed.
    dependsOn 'cleanTest'

    // Show test results.
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

PS For the absolute minimal version, see [Ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558072/4126843).

### Android (See this post: [JUnit 5 for Android testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53674289/8583692))

On Android I managed to run the JUnit 5 test from the question by adding the following to my app module build file. As you can see the dependencies are the same, but I didn't need `useJUnitPlatform()` and the test configuration block is slightly different.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// In fact I am not sure you need this, but I had it included to run Spek tests anyway
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5' 

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}


android {
    // I'm omitting your other configurations like compileSdkVersion, buildTypes etc.

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {

            // Always run tests, even when nothing changed.
            dependsOn 'clean'

            // Show test results.
            testLogging {
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**however**, it only works for me when I execute the Gradle `test` task, *not* when I run the `check` task. As usual, I test this by creating a failing test and then I try if the Gradle task passes or fails.

Comment: At the time of this writing Gradle built-in support is still missing out on a few features that might be important for you. See e.g. the following github issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4605

Comment: @johanneslink Thanks for pointing out! That was not an issue for me but good to know, and looks like it's in progress :)

Comment: Can we use JUnit5 on android without additional library?

Comment: @toffor Yes, I was able to run the test from the question (pay attention to the imports, they are different from JUnit 4) with the Gradle `check` task by just adding the two dependencies to my existing Android app. Will add that to the answer.

Comment: For newer versions of Gradle (I tested Gradle 7.0.2), replace `test {` with `tasks.withType(Test) {` for Groovy DSL or `tasks.withType<Test> {` for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70591817/8583692).

Comment: @Mahozad You mean on Android? Because for desktop applications, it works fine as is for me, so `tasks.test {` for the Kotlin DSL and `test {` for Groovy. Thanks for adding the link to your Android answer anyway.

Comment: I think you're right. It's on Android.
You're welcome.

Answer (score 16):

just adding to the knowledge base, i just got the following to work with gradle 4.7:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a more minimal example! I think using the `plugins` block instead of `apply plugin` is the [future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353244/4126843), but at the moment it is not critical.

Answer (score 7):

Due to github [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1037) built-in support for JUnit 5, scheduled for Gradle 4.6

Thus since gradle 4.6 your expected result have to be the same as actual result.

> **Expected result**: Tthe JUnit 4 test gave a nice 'passed' in the output
>   and an html report in `build/reports/tests`.

UPD:

gradle 4.6-rc-1 was released on 16th of February 2018 and this version provides the built-in support for junit 5.

To enable junit 5 support you need to update gradle wrapper:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version=4.6-rc-1
```

and add just one line to build.gradle:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [junit official documentation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.4.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle) of how to use junit 5 with gradle.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.0')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am glad they have improved their documentation since this question was asked, I will add a link to it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**) here is all you need to be able to run **JUnit 5 and/or JUnit 4 tests together**:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform() // Enables JUnit Platform (JUnit 5 + JUnit 4)
}

dependencies {
    // Aggregator dependency that also brings JUnit 5 parameterized tests etc.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.0")

    // Include the Vintage engine to be able to run JUnit 4 tests as well
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.10.0")
}
```

*src/test/java/com/example/MyTestClass.java*:

```java
package com.example

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
//...

public class MyTestClass {
    @Test // <- JUnit 5 test
    public void jUnit5test() {
        // ...
    }

    @org.junit.Test // <- JUnit 4 test
    public void jUnit4Test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Execute your tests by running the Gradle task `test` or `check` like this:

```bash
./gradlew test
```

Or, to execute only some tests:

```bash
./gradlew test --tests "com.example.MyTestClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something helpful for those who were struck with this problem when trying to integrate **JUnit5** with gradle version **4.10**.

```
Could not find method test() for arguments [build_dzas89s5z18l3bfyn6b3q0dxv$_run_closure2$_closure9@8e60c6] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Actually, with 4.10 you don't need to add this test configuration block in build.gradle to enable JUnit5.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

It should work fine just by adding the necessary dependencies of jupitor-api and jupitor-engine.

I tried to explore release notes of 4.10 but couldn't find anything about this change. If someone knows more about the "Why" behind it then please englighten me as well.

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer, although I cannot reproduce that error, and I still need the `useJUnitPlatform()` otherwise my tests won't run (even on Gradle 5.0), I'm curious what happened here. Anyway, hopefully this will be useful for other people. (edit: maybe you're using Gradle for an Android project. That may be the difference.)

Comment: I hit a similar error: `Could not find method test() for arguments [build_ejzeh5kmeasn8zq3a46rzrkon$_run_closure4@49e05c95] on root project 'xxxxx' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`, I think it happen because I put `test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}` outside of `subprojects { ... }`,  if I move it to inside of `subprojects { ... }`, this error disappeared