# IntelliJ Idea 2017.3 unable to start Kotlin Spring Boot App - @Configuration class may not be final

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I was able to launch a Spring Boot Kotlin App from IntelliJ 2017.3. After the last IntelliJ fix update I cannot start that application from the IDE, getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'AccessConfig' may not be final
```

I can start it from a terminal as usual: `java -jar xxxx.jar`

This doesn't make any sense since I am using the necessary Kotlin Spring plugin in my Gradle config:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.21'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RC1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3'
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'
...
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M5'
    mmaReleaseTrainVersion = 'Callao-SNAPSHOT'
    junitVersion = '5.0.2'
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

A simpler way to reproduce, just create a Spring Boot project with the Spring initializer from IntelliJ, you'll see the same result:

**DemoApplication:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'DemoApplication' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
Offending resource: com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed upgrading IntelliJ's Kotlin pluging to 1.2.21: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/update/42501

Comment: thanks, in my case i had the newest Kotlin plugin 1.3.72 and what helps me, was disable and enable plugin.

Comment: @Marosinho I have the latest plugin version (203-1.4.30-release-IJ7148.5) and I had to disable and re-enable for this to work. Thanks for solving my issue :)

Answer (score 31):

First of all, it's all due to class Kotlin [class definition](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html):

> The `open` annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's `final`: it allows others to inherit from this class. By default, all classes in Kotlin are final

so if you are free to modify your source code, you can make your class not final, just adding `open` to it's signature as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

or one of the possible solutions, according to this [article](https://github.com/pivotal/blog/blob/master/content/post/spring-boot-application-with-kotlin.md):

> The `@SpringBootApplication` is a convenience annotation that marks the class with the `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations. It is the `@Configuration` annotation that forces the use of the open keyword.

Is to try to remove the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and annotate your class with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can always add open as you suggest but this is pretty inconvenient, especially since I am using other libs that don't have it. So far the kotlin-spring plugin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#spring-support was working ok. I would like to make it work again.

Comment: @codependent I don't really understand, how it could work, since it's a spring requirement to any class annotated configuration to be not final. But in any way, you can avoid it substituting the `@SpringBootApplication` with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` if you application class is not a not a configuration.

Comment: It was working thanks to this plugin applied in the gradle.build: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'`. It was opening every Kotlin class annotated with @Configuration, etc. In fact it works when I run the application with java -jar which means that is actually opening those classes. However IntelliJ doesn't seem to be applying it.

Answer (score 3):

If you get this error on IntelliJ, even with kotlin-spring plugin, you may want to check if the annotation processing has been enabled in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

If plugin update does not help, check if version of kotlin in gradle matches ide's kotlin version.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have open behavior default to all Spring related classes in kotlin, you can use
`kotlin-allopen` plugin from here

https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ckotlin%20allopen

More info :
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-allopen-spring

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me (just add the following line to plugins):

```
plugins {
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring" version "1.5.10"
}
```

Or this approach:

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
}
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
```

Or in Maven:

```
<compilerPlugins>
<plugin>spring</plugin>
</compilerPlugins>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For not Spring Applications do the following:

```
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.5.10"
}
```

or this approach:

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
}
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"
```

After that specify the list of annotations that will make classes open

```
allOpen {
annotation("com.my.Annotation")
}
```

Or work with meta-annotations:

```
@com.my.Annotation
annotation class MyFrameworkAnnotation

@MyFrameworkAnnotation
class MyClass //all-open
```

how to use all-open with Maven:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
<version>${kotlin.version}</version>

<configuration>
    <compilerPlugins>
        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
    </compilerPlugins>

    <pluginOptions>
        <option>all-open:annotation=com.my.Annotation</option>
        <option>all-open:annotation=com.their.AnotherAnnotation</option>
    </pluginOptions>
</configuration>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```