# Running JUnit Test works but Gradle Tests does not. How to fix?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I am writing a game in libGDX using IntelliJ. I am writing the tests and having difficulty running them using `gradle test`. I get the error:

```
error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
```

`org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0` is in the Gradle dependencies. I have included `repositories(mavenCentral())` in build.gradle. I have followed the documentation for Gradle 4.6 and JUnit 5 so also have the following:

```
test{
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

However this seems to make no difference. Whenever I change the dependencies it affects whether I can run the JUnit tests so I know it is using them. It is just that when I run `gradle test` I get that error. How can I fix this?

Comment: this works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558072/51292

Comment: my example was for gradle 4.7

Comment: I would recommend including entire (minimal) build.gradle file in the question, otherwise it is difficult to understand your issue. Even better if you could make a GitHub repository with sample project that illustrates your problem. BTW, what Gradle version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it went away when i added that dependency down there. Might be that

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
    }
}
```

Since we do not know how you added junit to the build.gradle, maybe leave a comment to let us know.