# Could not find method test() for arguments on Android studio project

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, android-junit

In my Android application, I want exclude some test cases in a package so that I used `test` task in `build.gradle` file. for example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

test{
     exclude '**/calltest/Summary.class'
}
```

If sync the project I got following exception:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':SdkModule'.
> Could not find method test() for arguments [build_4g3vf7b615x3x1p7i9ty0pt1l$_run_closure1@73d026ca] on project ':SdkModule' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

If I add `apply plugin : 'java'`

```
CONFIGURE FAILED in 1s
The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 6):

Got similar problem when try to generate XML test report for my Jenkins build.
Test related settings should be in `testOptions`. My file:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    unitTests.all {
        reports {
            junitXml.enabled = true
            html.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
test {
    exclude '**/calltest/Summary.class'
}
```

try in Groovy

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    exclude '**/calltest/Summary.class'
}
```

or in [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts)

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    exclude("**/calltest/Summary.class")
}
```

Comment: Must be inside module's `build.gradle` not root